# How to read a string with newlines and store into Pandas dataframe or python list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file, data-structures

I read in a large text file with a custom data format like so:

```
file_object = open(file, "r")
contents = file_object.read()
```

printing contents will give something like this (the whole 'object' is just a string with new lines):

```
object name {
    # Data Type 1
    burgers [taste="good" type="food"];
    sushi [taste="good" type="food"];

    # Data Type 2
    NYC [population="300" type="urban"];
    
    # Data Type 3
    NYC -> CHI [distance="15.0"];

    LA -> SF [distnace="2.0"];
}
```

The data is grouped into 3 sections denoted by the #. The data can have inconsistent new lines inside/between sections so I want to remove all empty newlines first then I want to find out how to remove the tabs/white spaces preceding the data in each line like so.

```
object name {
# Data Type 1
burgers [taste="good" type="food"];
sushi [taste="good" type="food"];
# Data Type 2
NYC [population="300" type="urban"];
# Data Type 3
NYC -> CHI [distance="15.0"];
LA -> SF [distnace="2.0"];
}
```

and then from there figure out how to break it into 3 corresponding sections. I am not sure what data structure would be best since the format varies throughout (or if there is an easier way to read this thing in). Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Reading and preprocessing everything first may not be required: `for line in file_object: line=line.strip() if 0==len(line): continue` is a rather common idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
contents = """
object name {
    # Data Type 1
    burgers [taste="good" type="food"];
    sushi [taste="good" type="food"];

    # Data Type 2
    NYC [population="300" type="urban"];

    # Data Type 3
    NYC -> CHI [distance="15.0"];

    LA -> SF [distnace="2.0"];
}
"""

all_lines = contents.split("\n")

selected_lines = [line.strip() for line in all_lines if len(line) > 0]

new_contents = "\n".join(selected_lines)

print(new_contents)
```

The results are in `new_contents`.

**Edit (answer to comment):**

At this point you can split the string into sections:

```
lines = new_contents.split("\n")

# remove first and last lines
lines = lines[1:-1]

sections = {}
for line in lines:
  if "#" in line:
    # create new key (Data type X)
    key = line[2:]
    # value of new key is an empty list
    sections[key] = []
  else:
    # append row to key (Data type X)
    sections[key].append(line)

print(sections)
```

Comment: How would I take the 3 sections and put them into a data structure like a list of string rows or a dataframe?

Comment: See my edit - the `sections` will be a dict with each key containing a list of strings. Maybe you can use this to convert `sections` to a dataframe: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Answer (score 1):

I would just process the lines at the time they are read, and store them in a dict of lists of list of lists:

```
with open(file, "r") as file_object:
    data = {}
    section = None
    for line in file_object:
        line = line.strip()
        if 0 == len(line):
            continue
        if line.startswith('#'):
            section = []
            data[line[1:] = section
        elif section is not None:
            section.append(line)
```

You should end with the following dict of lists:

```
{' Data Type 1': [
    'burgers [taste="good" type="food"];',
    'sushi [taste="good" type="food"];'
    ],

 ' Data Type 2': ['NYC [population="300" type="urban"];'],
 { Data Type 3': [
    'NYC -> CHI [distance="15.0"];',
    'LA -> SF [distnace="2.0"];',
    '}'
    ]
}
```